# UICollectionView not reloading cell's imageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, reload

I have the below code called within :

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Unfortunately, when I call `[collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];` the imageView within the does not update. If I call reloadData, it does. I'm trying to keep the code as efficient as possible, so I do not want to just call reloadData. Would anyone have some insight on why this isn't working or what else I need to do? I've already had a few other issues with loading up numerous API image queries that conflict with the collectionView's lovely endAnimations stuff. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  SearchResultsCollectionViewCell *searchResultCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([SearchResultsCollectionViewCell class]) forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Product *product = self.products[indexPath.row];

    UIImage *productImage = [self.imageCache imageForURL:product.fullImageUrl];


    if (productImage) {
        searchResultCell.productImageView.image = productImage;
    } else {
        [self.imageCache downloadImageForURL:product.fullImageUrl indexPath:indexPath withCompletion:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                 searchResultCell.productImageView.image = image;
//                [collectionView reloadData];
                [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
            }

        }];
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"001_logo"];
        searchResultCell.productImageView.image = image;
    }
```

Comment: The first thing to note (but I don't think it is the cause) is that you change the code `indexPath.row` to `indexPath.item`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are accessing and storing the images seems odd.

The way I would do this is to create a `@property` for a `UIImage` on the `productImage`.

Then you can ask the product for its image. If the product returns a nil image then put a placeholder in the cell.

When the download is complete you can then reload the cells.

Secondly, I wouldn't try to change the cell in the completion block of the download call you are making.

The completion block should update the model (I.e. Store the image into the product object) and then reload the cell.

The reason for this is that you don't know for certain that the cell you are running the completion block  on is (a) the same cell as the one you started it on or (b) it is still displaying the same product.

Comment: It should but it doesn't, I personally didn't design the way the images are currently caching (which is the oddity that you see). It's odd because I can confirm that the proper image downloads and is returned... but when the reloadItemsAtIndexPaths is called, it seems to queue up. If I do this method this way, then an error eventually pops up saying I've hit the animation limit for a UIView which is about 31/32 I think. I would assume it's the same cell via the index path reference. If I run this completionBlock as a delegate method instead... it works fine.

Comment: Have you removed the call to set the image in the completion block? The completion block should only run reload... Also, make sure it is on the main thread. Set a breakpoint and look at the thread number. It should be 1. If it isn't then you'll need to push it onto the main thread.

Comment: I already tried wrapping everything in 'dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{' to ensure that without luck. The reason it shouldn't run reload and runs reloadItemsAtIndexPaths is because it refreshes individual cells on an individual basis when their images are done downloading from a network call. Everything is on the main thread though (I wish it was that easy).

Comment: So... any particular reason for the down vote after 2 years?